# Use delay on jQuery Animation

Tags: jquery, animation, delay

I am using this code to animate 3 divs, How can I add delay so that animation will happen step by step. Now 3 divs are animate on same time. Please help me.

Here is my code:
$(document).ready(function() {

```
//iPhone Animation / Define Variable
var iPhoneOne = $(".iphoneOne");
var iPhoneTwo = $(".iphoneTwo");
var free = $(".free");

iPhoneOne.animate({marginTop:'80px',opacity:1},{duration:"slow", easing:"easeOutBounce"});
iPhoneTwo.animate({marginTop:'80px',opacity:1},{duration:"slow", easing:"easeOutBounce"});
free.show("fast");
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this would be one way of doing it:

```
iPhoneOne.animate(
   {marginTop:'80px',opacity:1},
   {duration:"slow", easing:"easeOutBounce"},
   function()
   {

      iPhoneTwo.animate(
         {marginTop:'80px',opacity:1},
         {duration:"slow", easing:"easeOutBounce"},
         function()
         {

             free.show("fast");

         }
      );

   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Here is the code:
$(document).ready(function() {

```
//iPhone Animation / Define Variable
var iPhoneOne = $(".iphoneOne");
var iPhoneTwo = $(".iphoneTwo");
var free = $(".free");

iPhoneOne.animate({marginTop:'80px',opacity:1},{duration:"slow", easing:"easeOutBounce"});
iPhoneTwo.delay(500).animate({marginTop:'80px',opacity:1},{duration:"slow", easing:"easeOutBounce"});
free.delay(800).show("fast");
```

});